# A book on linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, reference-request

I am looking for a book on linear inequalities ( not on vector).

Interested in basic inequality theorems like Cauchy-Schwarz , Triangle inequality, Weirstrass' inequality, Chebychev's inequality

Comment: see here http://www.cimt.org.uk/projects/mepres/book9/bk9_13.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can try any of the following list

$\star$     Secrets In Inequalities volume 1 - Basic Inequalities - Pham Kim Hung.

$\star$     Secrets In Inequalities volume 2 - Advanced Inequalities - Pham Kim Hung.

$\star$    Algebraic Inequalities - Old And New Methods - Vasile Cirtoaje.

$\star$    Old And New inequalities volume 1 - Titu Andreescu, Vasile Cirtoaje, Gabriel Dospinescu, Mircea Lascu.

$\star$    Old And New Inequalities volume 2 - Vo Quoc Ba Can, Cosmin Pohoata.

$\star$    The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class - J. Michael Steele.

$\star$   Inequalities: A Mathematical Olympiad Approach - Radmila Bulajich Manfrino, Jose Antonio Ortega, Rogelio Valdez Delgado.

$\star$    An Introduction to Inequalities - Bellman, Beckenbach.

$\star$ Analytic Inequalities - Mitrinovic.

Comment: do you have old and new inequalities volume 2

Comment: @Soham Chatterjee Nope